# Not able to understand the Class behaviour{JAVA Interface}

Tags: java, interface

```
interface BankTransaction
{ 
    void transcation(); 
}
class Customer 
{
    protected double rate;

    //do something
}

class CurrentAccount extends Customer implements BankTransaction
{
    private double x;

    // do something

    public void transcation()
    {   
        // x is not able to communicate with rate
        x = rate * 1 / 100;
    }       
}
```

The program work when I do this

```
interface BankTransaction
{ 
    void transcation(Customer C); 
}
class Customer 
{
    protected double rate;

    //do something
}

class CurrentAccount extends Customer implements BankTransaction
{
    private double x;

    // do something

    public void transcation(Customer C)
    {
        x = C.rate * 1 / 100;
    }       
}
```

I Know that if I call `Customer` via `transcation` function, it will work.

Question is, why cannot `CurrentAccount` class communicate with the `Customer` class even I have extended it?

Why the 1st program doesn't work?

Let take rate = 10 and I want to calculate `x` with the help of rate, answer should have been 0.1 but I am getting 0 every time.

Java file:

```
interface BankTransaction
{ 
  void transcation(); 
 }
 class Customer
 { 
   Scanner KB = new Scanner(System.in);
   private int code;
   private String name;
   protected double balance;
    void openAccount()
    {
      System.out.print("Enter Code:");
      code = KB.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter Name:");
      Scanner KB = new Scanner(System.in);
      name = KB.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter balance:");
      balance = KB.nextDouble();
    }
    public void showAccount()
    {
      System.out.println("Code is "+code);
      System.out.println("Name is "+name);
      System.out.println("Balance is "+balance);
    }
 }
class CurrentAccount extends Customer implements BankTransaction
{ 
  private double totaltransaction;
  private double totaltax;
  public void transcation()
  { totaltransaction++;
    totaltax=balance*1/100;
  }
  public void showAccount()
  {
    System.out.println("Total Tax is "+totaltax);
    System.out.println("Total Transaction is "+totaltransaction);
  }
}


class Test
{ 
  public static void main(String arg[])
   { 
     Customer  C=new Customer();
     C.openAccount();
     C.showAccount();
     BankTransaction B;
     CurrentAccount CA=new CurrentAccount();
     B=CA;
     B.transcation();
     CA.showAccount();


   }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.. Please clear it or write the calling line.

Comment: Can you show evidence that "x is not able to communicate with rate"?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: There is no error.

Comment: let take rate = 10 and I want to calculate x with the help of rate, answer should have been 0.1 but I am getting 0.

Comment: How do you initialize rate with value of 10 ?

Comment: There is no error and it gives output as expected.

Comment: You probably do not set `rate`  when you initialize `CurrentAccount` class. Show us how you create an instance of `CurrentAccount` and how you call `transaction` method.

Comment: The first code example is fine. The problem must lie in how you initialise the field `rate` which you have not shown us.

Comment: I have added the java file please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main` method is where your mistake is:

```
Customer  C=new Customer();
C.openAccount();
C.showAccount();
BankTransaction B;
CurrentAccount CA=new CurrentAccount();
B=CA;
B.transcation();
CA.showAccount();
```

Here you created a `Customer` object and a `CurrentAccount` object. Although `CurrentAccount` inherits from `Customer`, the two objects are completely independent. Changes to one object will not affect the other.

This means that `CA`'s fields (`code`, `name`, and `balance`) will not be set when you call `openAccount` on `C`. Instead, `C`'s fields will be set.

When you do `B=CA`, `B` and `CA` now refer to the same `CurrentAccount` object. So `B.transaction` will change the `totalTax` of the `CurrentAccount` object, using the fields of the `CurrentAccount` object, which are, not set!

To fix this, don't create an extra `Customer` object and just use one `CurrentAccount` object:

```
CurrentAccount  C=new CurrentAccount();
C.openAccount();
C.showAccount();
BankTransaction B;
B=C;
B.transcation();
C.showAccount();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is in the main function.

```
class Test { 
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Customer  C=new Customer();
        C.openAccount();
        C.showAccount();
        BankTransaction B;
        CurrentAccount CA=new CurrentAccount();
        B=CA;
        B.transcation();
        CA.showAccount();
   }
}
```

The Customer C object that you are creating is not linked to the CurrentAccount CA object that you are creating. Since CA inherits the Customer object, it also inherits the public openAccount() method. So you can directly call it on the CA object. Same goes with transcation() method.

Just change your main function to this, and it will work:

```
class Test { 
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        CurrentAccount CA=new CurrentAccount();
        CA.openAccount();
        CA.transcation();
        CA.showAccount();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter Code:123
Enter Name:ABC
Enter balance:10
Total Tax is 0.1
Total Transaction is 1.0
```